# I am trying to solve the N queens problem using specific constraints in Z3

Tags: python, logic, z3

To solve the N queens problem in Z3 I have 5 combinations of propositional logic. I am struggling to set up the for loops the way they are required.`

```
from z3 import *


n = 4

Q =[[Bool("x_%s_%s" % (i+1,j+1)) for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]#creating nxn matrix;
Q1 = []
Z = []
for i in range(n):
    X = []
    for j in range(n):
        X.append(Q[i][j])
    Z.append(Or(X))
Q1.append(And(Z))



Q2 = []

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-1):
        Z = []
        for k in range(j+1,n):
            Z.append(Or(Not(Q[i][j]),Not(Q[i][k])))
        Q2.append(And(Z))
    


        


    
Q3 = []
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(n-1):
        Z = []
        for k in range(i+1,n):
            Z.append(Or(Not(Q[i][j]),Not(Q[k][j])))
        Q3.append(And(Z))

Q4 = []
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(n-1):
        Z = []
        for k in range(min(i-1,n-j)):
            Z.append(Or(Not(Q[i][j]),Not(Q[i-k][k+j])))
        Q4.append(And(Z))

Q5 = []
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-1):
        Z = []
        for k in range(min(n-i,n-j)):
            Z.append(Or(Not(Q[i][j]),Not(Q[i+k][k+j])))
        Q5.append(Z)


    


        


eight_queens_c = Q1 + Q2 + Q3 

s = Solver() 
s.add(eight_queens_c)
if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    r = [[m.evaluate(Q[i][j]) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    print_matrix(r)
else:
    print ("failed to solve")
```

`

I setup the for loops in a way that seemed fine to me but z3 is returning unsat which shouldnt be the case for a 4x4 matrix in my case. I have tried printing the actual lists to see what exactly they look like but they look fine to me. Attached is a picture of the required logic im pretty sure the code I wrote adheres to the constraints its just a matter of where I put the And and Or statements in the loops

[image of constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/083bR.png)

Comment: When I run your program, it doesn't say `unsat`. It does print the output, but it's not correct. So, I gather the program you posted isn't the actual program you're commenting about?